Why in SAP B1 when I cancel a Purchase Order the Purchase Request is cancelled?
your support, how to cancel the Purchase Order without canceling the Purchase Request, SAP B1 version is 10.0
Purchase Order and 
Purchase Request


It's so easy. Open your purchase Order (PO) and right click in the empty area of purchase order header then you got option to Cancel. Click on Cancel and then Update the PO Document. It just cancel the PO. The PR which linked with this PO will be fall in Open Status automatically.
